# HTTP Error 411 for startOptimization request of routeoptimization api

Tags: java, http, ptv-developer

I'm trying to send a startOptimization request to https://api.myptv.com/routeoptimization. I generated my java client as described in the tutorial: https://developer.myptv.com/Tutorials/General/clientGeneration.htm

Creating a plan works but when I want to optimize it I get the following error:

```
HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length.
```

I noticed that this error is also returned when I send a startEvaluation request. All other requests of the route optimization api and all other APIs seems to work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a bug in the API Managment of Microsoft. We created a ticket for Microsoft but we don't know when it is fixed.
The problem is that the API Managment rejects POST requests with an empty body where no Content-Length header of 0 is passed. The java client does not pass this header for an empty body, therefore either the empty body must be avoided or the header must be added until the bug is fixed.

There are two possible solution to solve this problem:

1. Just pass a dummy body which is ignored anyway. For this you have to adapt the java client after generation:
   replace all occurencies of

```
localVarRequestBuilder.method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.noBody());
```

with

```
try {
  byte[] localVarPostBody = memberVarObjectMapper.writeValueAsBytes("dummybody");
  localVarRequestBuilder.method("POST", HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofByteArray(localVarPostBody));
} catch (IOException e) {
  throw new ApiException(e);
}
```

2. Explicitly send a Content-Length header of 0 by adding

```
System.setProperty("jdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders", "Content-Length");
```

to a setup method of your main and adding

```
localVarRequestBuilder.header("Content-Length", "0");
```

to the `startEvaluationRequestBuilder` and `startOptimizationRequestBuilder` methods.